# Very long repeated compile time for building LLVM from sources

Tags: cmake, compilation, clang, llvm, ninja

Steps for reproduce:

1. Build LLVM from sources.
2. Change something in one cpp file.
3. Build LLVM again. Not a long compile time for that case because I've changed only one cpp file, that's ok.
   **But** if I reboot computer after changing cpp file or wait some long time and try to build LLVM after that again, compile time will be very long, like in first step. But I've changed only one cpp file. Why it's happens and how can I avoid this?

Cmake command:

```
cmake -G Ninja ../llvm \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang \
```

Ninja command:

```
ninja -j 4 -l 1
```

Comment: `ninja -v` will show you the commands that are run. My guess is that you've changed one file, and one file needs to be recompiled and then eleventy-four libraries and executables need to be relinked.

Comment: Could be because of the many things the Operating System does. For example, when rebuilding without rebooting, most of the stuff required for compilation might already be in RAM which helps speed up the build. When you reboot, RAM has nothing on it and everything has to be fetched again.

Comment: @arnt, thank you, will try this flag.